# How to make Atom display output in Terminal

Tags: atom

I'm trying to run a `c++` program in `Atom`. I installed the gpp-compiler package, and it's running my program when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

1. It's outputting to `XTerm` (linux terminal). How can I make it output to the normal Terminal.
2. When there is an error in the program, the errors are just popping up for 5 seconds, and then fading away, can I make it so they appear in the terminal?

So I changed 'XTerm' to 'GNOME Terminal' but now the terminal isn't staying open long enough to observe the output.

I don't want to just open the terminal from Atom, I want to be able to press a button, and have it compile and run my C++ code. That's the entire purpose of the gpp-compiler package.

Comment: Not an expert but you can add a command to accept a key entry in your code to delay the terminal.

Comment: What's a "gpp-compiler"?

Comment: @David, you can download that package for atom. It allows you to compile and run c++ programs from directly within Atom.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. It would be good to distinguish between Atom packages and Debian/Ubuntu packages.